# Package tm in R returning 'subscript out of bounds' every time the TDM is accessed

Tags: r, tm

I have a TDM of 1,500 tweets:

```
> twdf_tdm
A term-document matrix (625 terms, 1500 documents)

Non-/sparse entries: 15366/922134
Sparsity           : 98%
Maximal term length: 26 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

I am trying to run various functions on it from the tm and the tm.plugin.sentiment packages, but get the 'subscript out of bounds' error. This happens both with the Corpus the TDM is based on...:

```
> score(twdf_corpus)
Error in slam:::`[.simple_triplet_matrix`(x, i, j, ...) : 
  Subscript out of bounds.
```

...and the TDM itself...:

```
> polarity(twdf_tdm)
Error in slam:::`[.simple_triplet_matrix`(x, i, j, ...) : 
  Subscript out of bounds.
```

I suspect tm to be involved, but I can find no solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update your Q to show all the packages you're using and enough of your data so that we can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Wouldn't it have been more courteous to explain that you got one of these packages from R-Forge?